# javac not generating class files when there are errors

Tags: java, javac

I'm a hobby coder using CodeAnywhere to allow me to, well, code anywhere without having to set up a development environment. It's admittedly not the fullest featured IDE, but it gets the job done. One limitation is that I can't use Ant or Maven, so I have to figure out how to build using plain old javac (via SSH).

So I've created a little bash script that creates a file with the relative paths to all the source files, and then pumps that into javac:

```
find -name *.java > classes.txt
javac @classes.txt
```

The first line works fine and generates the anticipated output. The second one also appears to work, and even gives me compile errors (which I was expecting). However, there are a few classes that should compile, but the corresponding class files are not generated. Is this anticipated behavior? Why does it work when I manually include multiple file names as arguments (even when I include ones that generate errors), but not when I use the @file notation?

Comment: Try `javac $(find . -name "*.java")`. You might also consider a different IDE that supports Maven, Ant, SBT or Gradle.

Comment: Not supporting a build tool (like ant or gradle) is actually a pretty big deal.  Netbeans is simple and lightweight, and supports Java fully.  I don't think it runs on a phone, but it runs on pretty much anything else.

Comment: I guess javac stops the process when it has listed enough number of errors. Anyway when there is a compile time failure, it does not matter even if it generates classes for java files which are fine. You will not run the application unless the application compiles completely.

Comment: @markspace I use CodeAnywhere so I can code from my phone. If you can find another way for me to do that easily, I'm open.

Comment: @gagansingh sometimes the compile errors are in pluggable components that aren't currently in use, so they can fail compilation without affecting the runtime process.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch nope, didn't work, same outcome.

Comment: It's hard to help without more information, but using `javac` alone is going to make your life needlessly more difficult.

Comment: Do the file names appear in the same order in `classes.txt` as what you have when you include them directly in the command line? It would help if you could give us a short, specific example (say, with two files, including full source) where it behaves differently when using the `@file` syntax and when listing the files directly on the command line.

Comment: Ugh, order does matter apparently. Any way to re-write my script so it calls javac on each file individually?

Comment: `while read in; do javac "$in"; done < classes.txt` did the trick

Comment: It can't compile classes that depend on classes with errors.

Comment: You can't use Maven or Gradle wrapper which don't require you to install anything on that server?

Comment: If someone can point me to instructions on how to set up and use Ant, Maven, or Gradle on CodeAnywhere, I'll look into it, but honestly I get so little time to code that I don't want to waste it trying to configure my environment.